# Sitecore Web db automatic creation possible?

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to start Sitecore with just Master and Core? We first go to content editor and then publish. Through this we expect web Db to be created. Which one below is correct

1. On publish Web db will be automatically created based on the name in connection string?
2. On publish Web db will not be created. Web db should exist and should have the correct schema for the publish to happen.
3. Web db should be setup by creating a copy of Master db, and this will be overwritten on publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to start Sitecore just with `master` and `core` databases. It's called `Sitecore Live Mode`. You can read more about it e.g.

1. [Sitecore Live Mode - What, Why and When](http://www.verndale.com/insights/blog/2012/october/sitecore-live-mode/).
2. [How to run Sitecore in live mode](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-to-run-sitecore-in-live-mode/340).
3. [Sitecore Live Mode](http://sitecore-masters.com/en/sitecore-live-mode/)

But that means that content is served automatically from the `master` database so:

1. `web` database will not be created automatically
2. Yes, `web` database must exist if you want to be able to publish.
3. No, don't create `web` database by copying `master` database. Use empty `web` database from the clean Sitecore zip (use exactly the same version as your application).

Comment: I am not asking about live mode. Accessing from web db. Still your answers are valid right? We access web db or website only after publishing

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your comments. From what I see, you want automated `web` db creation and second part of my answer should cover all your doubts. By default Sitecore will NOT start if `web` database is not present in the place defined by connection string. Nothing will be created automatically. Take empty `web` database from the vanilla Sitecore installation and use publish everything from `master` database.

Answer (score 1):

To put this as an answer, **no** you can't have Sitecore create the web (or any) database if it doesn't exist.

Not that it would be impossible, but it doesn't do that out of the box, and it's a pretty unlikely use-case so I can't imagine them ever building such a feature.

Sitecore databases should be appropriately sized/scaled to meet a workload. In particular, the web db is public-facing, so requires particular tuning consideration that would be hard or impossible to predict through heuristics.

You could approach this via a PowerShell script launched at the start of the bootstrap pipeline (the one before initialize, I can't remember what it's called) otherwise the system will fail at startup when it tries to execute the connection string.